# Recalculating a variable inside a function on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function that opens and closes a navigation overlay which slides in under the header. It works perfectly click, but if I open the navigation then resize the window a space appears between the nav and the header. This is because when I click for the nav to open the height of the header is calculated then added to the top of the nav to offset it. But the size of the header isn't recalculated on resize. How can I do this? I know I could add a resize even on the function but I don't want the function to run on resize I just want the height of the header to be recalculate. Thanks.

```
jQuery("#button").click(function(){
        var nav = jQuery("#nav_overlay");
        var head_h = jQuery("#head_fixed").outerHeight(true);

        jQuery(nav).css("top", head_h);
        jQuery(nav).toggleClass('width_pad');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I had to declare my variables outside the function so that I could access them in another function, then recalculate them. Here it is.

```
    var nav = jQuery("#nav_overlay");
    var head_h = jQuery("#head_fixed").outerHeight(true);

    jQuery("#button").click(function(){
        var nav = jQuery("#nav_overlay");
        var head_h = jQuery("#head_fixed").outerHeight(true);

        jQuery(nav).css("top", head_h);
        jQuery(nav).toggleClass('width_pad');
    });

     jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        var head_h = jQuery("#head_fixed").outerHeight(true);
        jQuery(nav).css("top", head_h);
    });
```